# Restricted picklist value is throwing an error on creation of Case record from apex class

Tags: apex, case, picklist

My case object has a custom picklist which has around 20 values. However the Labels and API names are different for each of the values. Also restrict picklist value checkbox is checked for the picklist field.

Now my requirement is to create a case in my apex class. However, whenever I provide API value of one of the picklist values as string, it is throwing the following error

Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST, bad value for restricted picklist field: Auto PCG: [U_Product__c ]

Apex code

```
 Case caseObject = new Case(Country__c = country,
                               U_Product__c = 'Auto PCG',
                               Type = caseType,
                               MDue_Date__c = dueDateValue,                                
                              );
 insert caseObject;
```

What am I doing wrong here? I will not be able to uncheck the restrict picklist values checkbox

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the API Name of Picklist value in the code. If API Name is `Auto_PCG` and label is `Auto PCG` then use this as below. In the UI it will display the label of the picklist value.

```
Case caseObject = new Case(Country__c = country,
                               U_Product__c = 'Auto_PCG',
                               Type = caseType,
                               MDue_Date__c = dueDateValue,                                
                              );
 insert caseObject;
```

*Just a side note, if you have a support of different languages which can be done through translation workbench, there we assign different language specific values for same picklist label. So, API name will remain constant and values can be changed.*